# Match numbers that not in context of Value(x)

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying  to match the numbers that are not in the context of Value(X) and discard rest of text.

Example text:

```
 lorem ipsum Value (3) dfasdf 654345435ds sdfsdf asdf
asd
F
asdf
sad Value (2)
```

Example Regex:

```
 Value\((\d)\)
```

[image]

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .NET regex engine supports a quantifier in the lookbehind assertion.

What you might do is assert that from the current position, the is not `Value(` to the left that has 1+ digits and `)` to the right. If that is the case, match 1 or more digits.

The pattern matches:

```
(?<!\bValue[\p{Zs}\t]*\((?=[0-9]+\)))[0-9]+
```

- `(?<!` Positive lookbehind, assert what is to the left is

  - `\bValue` Match `Value` preceded by a word boundary to prevent a partial match
  - `[\p{Zs}\t]*\(` Match optional horizontal spaces followed by `(`
  - `(?=[0-9]+\))` Positive lookahead, assert 1+ digits followed by `)` to the right
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `[0-9]+` Match 1+ digits 0-9

[.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5cbValue%5b%5cp%7bZs%7d%5ct%5d*%5c%28%28%3f%3d%5b0-9%5d%2b%5c%29%29%29%5b0-9%5d%2b&i=+lorem+ipsum+Value+%283%29+dfasdf+654345435ds+sdfsdf+asdf%0d%0aasd%0d%0aF%0d%0aasdf%0d%0asad+Value+%282%29%0d%0aValu%282%29%0d%0a1%0d%0a%281%0d%0a2%29%0d%0a2%28%292%293afqlkfj23421rlfj4lj4fl+test%281234%29+Value%282%29)

Note that `\d` matches more digits than 0-9 only, but also from other languages. If you want match that, you can use `\d`, else you can use `[0-9]` instead.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for:

```
(?<!Value *\()\d+)
```

Note that I am assuming that every `Value(` has a closing bracket.

**Explanation:**

- `(?<!Value *\()` asserts that what follows it is not preceded by `"Value("`, `Value (`, `Value  (` and so on.
- `\d+` matches a digit between one and infinite times

Comment: No, your regex does not do what you explained. Your `(?!<Value *\()\d+(?!\))` regex is equal to `\d+(?!\))` (any one or more digits where the last digit is not immediately followed with `)`) because `(?!<Value *\()` is a lookahead, and not a lookbehind.

Comment: Sorry, swapped `!` and `<` erroneously. Now fixed.

Comment: But now, your `(?<!Value *\()\d+(?!\))` [will match](https://regex101.com/r/IK0jVo/1) `3` in `(34)`, not the expected `34`. Which is not meeting the requirements to only ignore one specific context.

Comment: So... the negative lookahead is not needed?

Comment: No, both are required, or not, depends on what approach to use, and the approach depends on what the OP wants/intends to do, and before we know that, we cannot answer.

Comment: So here I will be assuming that every `Value(` has a closing bracket.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ought to do you:

```cs
private static readonly Regex rx = new Regex(@"
  (?<!          # A zero-width negative look-behind assertion, consisting of:
    \w          #   - a word boundary, followed by
    Value       #   - the literal 'Value', followed by
    \s*         #   - zero or more whitespace characters, followed by
    [(]         #   - a left parenthesis '(', followed by
    \s*         #   - zero or more whitespace characters,
  )             # The whole of which is followed by
  (             # A number, consisting of
    -?          #   - an optional minus sign, followed by
    \d+         #   - 1 or more decimal digits,
    )           # The whole of which is followed by
  (?!           # A zero-width negative look-ahead assertion, consisting of
    \s*         #   - zero or more whitespace characters, followed by
    [)]         #   - a single right parenthesis ')'
  )             #
",
    rxOpts
  );

private const RegexOptions rxOpts = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
                                  | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture
                                  | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace
                                  ;
```

Then . . .

```cs
foreach ( Match m in rx.Matches( someText ) )
{
  string nbr = m.Value;
  Console.WriteLine("Found '{0}', nbr);
}
```